# Как сфокусировать элемент selenium

Tags: python, selenium, прокрутка

Пишу небольшой скрипт. Нужно узнать имена всех подписчиков. Проблема в том, что видно только первые 10 имен. И чтоб узнать все нужно пролистать полностью список до низу. Но есть одно но. Никак не удается сфокусироваться на каком-то элементе, чтоб от него уже отталкиваться и листать. Вот код:

```
def get_followers(self):
    try:
        self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a._t98z6')[0].click()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Sorry, i don't have access to your followers: {0}".format(e))
    else:
        followers = []
        while True:
            #Сдесь нужно как-то сфокусироваться на элементе.
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
            try:
                WebDriverWait(self.driver, 7).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='_6e4x5']")) 
            except Exception as e:
                print('{0}'.format(e))
                break
       followers = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a._2g7d5.notranslate._o5iw8")
```

Вопросы:

1. Как же правильно сфокусироваться чтоб можно было листать список?
2. Как узнать следующий элемент, если все элементы имеют один класс?

   `x.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='_6e4x5']"))` #*Вот здесь*.

Вот такой список:
[image: список]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
followers = []
while len(followers) != self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='_6e4x5']")):
    el = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='_6e4x5']"))[-1]
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", el)
    followers = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='_6e4x5']"))
```

1) Я не совсем понимаю что значит сфокусироваться, но можно листать список просто прокручивая список до нижнего элемента.

2) Дальше вложенные "внутри" элементы отличаются по title и text
Должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. Все работает. Но разве это будет нормально, что каждую итерацию перезаписывается followers?

Comment: А что не так?
Можно создать новую переменную new_followers и изменять её.